# nested fork() tree in c++

Tags: c++, loops, process, fork

This is sor far I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int p1,p2,p3,p4,i;
    int left,leftPid;
    int right;  
    left=fork();
    right=fork();
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        if(left==0)
            printf("\nleft Child Process. Level: %d | myPID: %d | myParent: %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid());    
        else
            leftPID=left;
        if (right==0)
        {
            printf("\nright Child Process. Level: %d | myPID: %d | myParent: %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid());
            right=fork();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nParent Process. Level %d | My left Child: %d | My right Child: %d | myPID: %d\n",i,leftPID,right,getpid());
        }
    }
}
```

And I need that kind of an output:

> > left Child Process. Level: 1 | myPID: 23560 | myParent: 23559
> >
> > Parent Process. Level: 0 | My left Child: 23560 | My right Child: 23561 | myPID: 23559
> >
> > left Child Process. Level: 2 | myPID: 23562 | myParent: 23561
> >
> > left Child Process. Level: 3 | myPID: 23564 | myParent: 23563
> >
> > right Child Process. Level: 3 | myPID: 23565 | myParent: 23563
> >
> > Parent Process. Level: 2 | My left Child: 23564 | My right Child: 23565 | myPID: 23564
> >
> > Parent Process. Level: 1 | My left Child: 23562 | My right Child: 23563 | myPID: 23561

And here is a tree representation what I need:

[image: fork() tree]

And the code I have did is far away from what I need. I hope there is someone to help me about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to keep in mind is that when fork() is called, the code below it is executed by child as well as parent. So you do need to put conditions for both of them by using the returned values of fork() system call.Now in your case, after calling left=fork(), the next statement which is right=fork() is executed by parent,which is right, but the same statement is executed by left child as well and you donot want that! so after the left=fork() system call is being used, put conditions for left child and parent so that they can execute their own corresponding paths of code. Another bug in your code is that right child is only making in turn a right child and not it's left child.

```
for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    left=fork();
    leftPID=left; 

    if(left==0) //use break statement for left child since we want it to be kicked out and not execute anything!
    {
        printf("\nleft Child Process. Level: %d | myPID: %d | myParent:                      %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid())
        break; // break statement has to used here necessarily or else left child  will keep on making left childs
    }         
    else if(left>0) //this is executed by parent
    {
        right=fork(); //parent forks a right child

        if (right==0) //this is executed by right child
        {
            printf("\nright Child Process. Level: %d | myPID: %d | myParent:                      %d\n",i,getpid(),getppid());
        } 
        else if(right>0) //executed by parent
        {
            printf("\nParent Process. Level %d | My left Child: %d | My right Child: %d | myPID: %d\n",i,leftPID,right,getpid());
            break; //again use break to kick out parent since now this parent has no work to do and break statement has to used here necessarily or else parent will keep on making childs-left and right
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
left=fork();
right=fork();
```

After this code, you end up with four processes - since every `fork()`'ed process will immediately fork again - why you want to have three. You need to make sure you check result of **each** fork call.

Taking this into account, you can re-write the other code.